# Unable to uninstall skype on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: skype, software-uninstall

I have skype installed and running at startup. I would like to remove it altogether. I've seen some advice online, but none of them work.

I can see several skypeforlinux processes running in the system monitor. When I run `sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux` I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package skypeforlinux
```

When I run `dpkg -S skype` I see a list of files of the form `ubuntu-docs: /usr/share/help/it/gnome-help/net-chat-skype.page` (I guess help documents in several languages) and nothing else. I don't see any Skype related entry in the **Startup Applications Preferences**, even though Skype launches itself on startup.

Any idea?

Comment: You've tor reinstall Skype and purge it using back-end tools like `dpkg`. How did you installed Skype?

Comment: Also add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i skype`; `snap list | grep -i skype`; `flatpak list | grep -i skype`; `find ~ -iname '*skype*'` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed it through snap, then

```
sudo snap remove --purge skype
```

if doesn't work try this cmd;

```
sudo apt --purge remove skype/skypeforlinux
```

After removing Skype find */.config/Skype* and into this directory type

```
rm -r Skype skypeforlinux
```

hope this help you.

Comment: `sudo snap remove --purge skype` worked, thanks! I couldn't find /.config/Skype though.

Comment: in a snap installation, the skype config file is stored in ~/snap

Comment: Thanks @s3idani. Found the folder, but it contains only a 'current' file which is a broken link to a "200" target (?!). I guess I can remove it.